# How do I run Jasmine in browser mode if my tests are written in Typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, jasmine, ts-node

I am using Jasmine to unit test some legacy code that will run in the browser. Here is how I execute my tests: `ts-node node_modules/jasmine/bin/jasmine`

Because this is legacy code, it's using globals (ie: `window`).  How do I execute Jasmine and tell it that it should assume the code is in browser mode as opposed to node mode.  That is, recognize `window` as a global variable and `global` as not?

Answer (score 0):

If jasmine is a hard requirement, you can use [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) to mimic browser environment in node.

```js
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
global.window = (new JSDOM()).window; // this will put window object on the node's global object.
```

If it is not a hard requirement, consider using jest, which has the entire jsdom setup built-in.

Comment: I have no need to access the Dom, I just need an empty window object that I can set and get things on. Does that give me another way to do it?

Comment: JSDom is exactly this, check the documentation

Comment: @DanielKaplan then just `global.window = {};`